# Service Unavailable

Tags: php, post

Cuando envío un `$_POST` a mi hosting recibo con mucha frecuencia este error:

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due
to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. 
Please try again later.
```

Ya he probado con `set_time_limit();` pero recibo el mismo resultado.

Curiosamente las peticiones por `$_GET` las procesa perfectamente incluso accediendo a la base de datos.

¿Realmente estará el servidor saturado o se tratará de otra cuestión? No utilizo ningún CMS ni framework, es un script muy sencillo en PHP

Comment: La mejor forma de averiguarlo es revisando los log de error. El mensaje parece claro: mantenimiento o problemas de capacidad. No sé si el hosting es de muy baja calidad, o si restringe de alguna forma las peticiones POST. Si el problema persiste podrías ponerte en contacto con su servicio técnico.

Comment: Pasa de vez en cuando, tiene toda la pinta de ser sobrecarga del servidor. La cuestión es que las peticiones por `$_GET` sí que las atiende...